# Problema na inserção do banco mysql em php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aplicação-web

estou desenvolvendo um projeto para a faculdade e estou tendo alguns problemas para efetuar a inserção no banco de dados my_sql, meu problema se encontra nesse trecho.

```
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO funcionario(
      codigo_funcionario,
      nome,
      cpf,
      data_nascimento,
      telefone,
      estado,
      motivo,
      periodo,
      cidade,
      rua,
      bairro,
      numero,
      complemento,
      cep,
      cnpj_empresa
    ) VALUES (
      '".$this->getCodigoDoFuncionario()."',
      '".$this->getNome()."',
      '".$this->getCPF()."',
      '".$this->getDataNascimento()."',
      '".$this->getTelefone()."',
      '".$this->getEstado()."',
      '".$this->getMotivo()."',
      '".$this->getPeriodo()."',
      '".$this->endereco->getCidade()."',
      '".$this->endereco->getRua()."',
      '".$this->endereco->getBairro()."',
      '".$this->endereco->getNumero()."',
      '".$this->endereco->getComplemento()."',
      '".$this->endereco->getCEP()."',
      ''
    );");
```

Meu problema se encontra no momento em que eu faço

```
'".$this->endereco->getCidade()."'
```

Não sei se o problema é com a minha classe, ou se é a sintaxe que está errada.

Estou tendo esses dois erros "Undefined property" e "Fatal error: Call to a member function getCidade() on null". 
Poderiam me dar uma ajuda?? Valeu!

Comment: Amigo, pelo erro que você tem "Fatal error: Call to a member function getCidade() on null", provavelmente você esqueceu de instanciar o objeto endereço.

Comment: A sim, realmente, meu __construct estava escrito construc ao invés de construct UAHAUHUAH, valeu cara!!

Comment: leandro, escreve a resposta para a pergunta para que Ricardo possa selecionar como escolhida e o post ficar como respondido.

Comment: Leia sobre [injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL), este é um problema muito sério que há em seu código.